# Any performance cost with using "when" instead of "if-else"?

Tags: kotlin

While developing, I've found that using `when` looks nicer a lot of the times compared to `if-else`. So, I'm curious whether using `when` instead of the typical `if-else` in simple situations have a performance impact (even if it's small). An example is doing:

```
val someNumber = when (someObject) {
    null -> 0
    else -> someCalculation()
}
```

versus

```
val someNumber = if (someObject == null) {
    0
} else {
    someCalculation()
}
```

Is there a performance difference between the two?

Comment: AFAIK it will be compiled to an if, since on the JVM you can't `switch` on anything that isn't an enum, a `String` or a primitive, so, there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: You could also do `val someNumber = someObject?.let { someCalculation() } ?: 0`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**tl;dr: No you should not expect `when` to slow anything down.**

The compiler reuses if/else, switch and ternary operator constructs in order to express `when` statements. Take this example:

```
fun whenApplication(someObject: String?) = when (someObject) {
    null -> 0
    else -> 2
}
```

And its bytecode shown as Java code:

```
public static final int whenApplication(@Nullable String someObject) {
   return someObject == null ? 0 : 2;
}
```

Slightly more complex when-tests are shown here:

```
fun whenApplication(someObject: Any?) = when (someObject) {
    is Int -> 2
    in 0..2 -> 4
    else -> 5
}
```

And the corresponding bytecode as Java:

```
public static final int whenApplication(@Nullable Object someObject) {
    int var10000;
    if (someObject instanceof Integer) {
       var10000 = 2;
    } else {
       byte var2 = 0;
       var10000 = CollectionsKt.contains((Iterable)(new IntRange(var2, 2)), someObject) ? 4 : 5;
    }

    return var10000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It does feel kinda weird for me to mark this as an answer cause it's like saying, "Yes, you are correct!". But given the explanation, I'm pretty sure it is. :D

Comment: Well elaborate.

Comment: I'll add that `when` isn't _always_ compiled to an `if` chain: depending on cases, it could be a `switch`, which is generally faster!